# Variable Scope in Blocks

Tags: ruby

David A Black (*The Well Grounded Rubyist*, Chapter 6) presents the following code:

```
def block_local_parameter
  x = 100
  [1,2,3].each do |x|
    puts "Parameter x is #{x}"
    x += 10
    puts "Reassigned to x in block; it is now #{x}"
  end
  puts "The value of outer x is now #{x}"
end

block_local_parameter
```

Expected output as per the book (Ruby 1.9.1):

> ```
> Parameter x is 1
> Reassigned to x in block; it's now 11
> Parameter x is 2
> Reassigned to x in block; it's now 12
> Parameter x is 3
> Reassigned to x in block; it's now 13
> Outer x is still 100
> ```

My output (Ruby 1.8.7):

> ```
> Parameter x is 1
> Reassigned to x in block; it's now 11
> Parameter x is 2
> Reassigned to x in block; it's now 12
> Parameter x is 3
> Reassigned to x in block; it's now 13
> Outer x is still 13
> ```

Is the book wrong? Or, am I missing something?

Comment: I think it's sometimes called shadowing, but to be honest I don't know what the word means: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259314/what-does-shadowing-mean-in-ruby

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you're seeing is the behavior for Ruby 1.8.x. Variable scope for blocks was introduced in 1.9, switch  to 1.9.x and you will get the same results as in the book.

Comment: Oh... BTW is there a way in Ruby 1.8.x to get declare a variable(x) local to the block so that I don't end up changing the other x variable?

Comment: @Prakhar: No. That feature was added in 1.9.