# proc changing class in irb

Tags: ruby, irb, proc-object

Just when I thought I had my head wrapped around procs & lambdas this happens...

```
irb> x = Proc.new{|name| "Hello #{name}"}
irb> x.class #=> Proc
irb> x.call("Bob") #=> "Hello Bob"
irb> x.class #=> String
irb> x #=> "Bob"
```

Why is `x` changing its class when called?

What am I misunderstanding and/or doing wrong here?

Comment: what ruby version are you using? it works as expected on `1.9.2` and `ree`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, there's a syntax error in your code, so I'm assuming you mean `x = Proc.new {|name| "Hello #{name}"}` instead of `x = Proc.new (|name| "Hello #{name}"}`.

Second, when I run your example code I don't get that behavior.

However, if the `name` variable were to be named the same as the variable name where you store the proc (`x` in your example), and you were using a ruby version prior to 1.9, you will get this behavior.

Here's an example of that (I use `x` as the name of the block variable, and this is ruby 1.8.7):

```
>> x = Proc.new {|x| "Hello #{x}"}
=> #<Proc:0x00000001013335b8@(irb):1>
>> x.class
=> Proc
>> x.call("Bob")
=> "Hello Bob"
>> x.class
=> String
>> x
=> "Bob"
```

The reason that happens is because you can overwrite a variable defined outside of the current scope in ruby pre 1.9. In ruby 1.9 this behavior is called shadowing, and is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259314/what-does-shadowing-mean-in-ruby).

Comment: BINGO on all counts! Thank you.