# In Ruby is it possible to create a local variable explicitly

Tags: ruby, variables, block, local, proc

e.g.

```
x = 123
p = Proc.new {
  x = 'I do not want change the value of the outer x, I want to create a local x'
}
```

In Ruby Is there something the same as "my" keyword in Perl ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per the **Perl** documentation of [**my**](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/my.html),I think you are looking for something like below in Ruby:-

```
x = 123 
p = Proc.new {|;x|  
  x = 'I do not want change the value of the outer x, I want to create a local x'
}
p.call 
# => "I do not want change the value of the outer x, I want to create a local x"
x # => 123
```

Answer (score 1):

Beware! (Related, though not *exactly* what you're asking...)

The rules for variable scope changed between 1.8 and 1.9. See [Variable Scope in Blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6254267/variable-scope-in-blocks)

```
x = 100
[1,2,3].each do |x|
```

behaves differently in the different versions. If you declare a variable in a block's || that has the same name as a variable outside the block, then in 1.8 it will change the value of the outer variable, and in 1.9 it will not.